# Execute procedure owned by a schema in sys

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, authid

I have a schema called test, and it has a procedure called `doAProcedure('varA')`. Inside the procedure it calls a function `funcA` that belongs to schema test.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE doAProcedure(tabname varchar2) AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS ....
```

If I log in to the db as test, I am able to complete `execute doAProcedure('valA');`

However, I want to support executing the procedure as SYS as well. if I execute the following command as sys, it is complaining that function `funcA` is not declared. `execute test.doAProcedure('varA');` Not sure what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in: `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`

This means that the current user must also be authorized to execute code inside the procedure.

Fix 1: Remove this part and leave only:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE doAProcedure(tabname varchar2) AS
```

Fix 2: Grant execute to function `funcA` for SYS

```
grant execute on test.funcA to sys;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Would this work in the case where i schedule jobs as sys,and run something like this 
 DECLARE jobno numeric;
 Next_Date Date;
 next_interval varchar2(20);
 BEGIN
 Select Last_Day(Sysdate) Into Next_Date From Dual;
 dbms_job.submit(jobno, 'begin test.doAProcedure(''varA''); end;',next_date,'Last_Day(Add_Months(Sysdate,5))'); COMMIT; END;
 /

Answer (score 0):

This is test case; everything works OK when connected as the owner:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@pdb1
Connected.
SQL> create or replace function f_test return number is
  2  begin
  3    return 1;
  4  end;
  5  /

Function created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_test authid current_user is
  2  begin
  3    dbms_output.put_line('Function returned ' || f_test);
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec p_test
Function returned 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Let's connect as `SYS` and try again:

```
SQL> connect sys@pdb1 as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> exec scott.p_test
BEGIN scott.p_test; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06598: insufficient INHERIT PRIVILEGES privilege
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P_TEST", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

As you said, it won't work.

"Problem" is in Oracle 12c or later, with new security feature (see [inherit privileges](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/release_changes.htm#LNPLS121)).

What to do? A little grant (still connected as `SYS`):

```
SQL> grant inherit privileges on user sys to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> exec scott.p_test
Function returned 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Now it works.